# Книги и мануалы по PyOpenGL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, книги

Здравствуйте! Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, книги и мануалы по PyOpenGL.

Comment: А с OpenGL на С уже знакомы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам api opengl везде одинаковый, так что надо учить именно его + документация к библиотеке, которая его поддерживает, например pyglet или тот же pyopengl

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 1):

Для начала изучи openGL для C++ . По нему книг намного больше , а концепции похожи. Да и вообще opengl отдельная и очень большая тема

Comment: Тема действительно большая, но интересная...
Спасибо за помощь!